# Function Triggers Incorrectly

Tags: visual-c++, console-application

Essentially, I am trying to develop a makeshift BlackJack game while learning C++. I have declared an array that holds my card values, but I have a value, that will hold two at one time. Whenever I run the application I notice it runs my `Ace()` function first, but I do not want it to do that. I want it to ask when the the random generator picks the `Ace()` function.

```
int main()
{
random_device rd;
mt19937 eng(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 11);

int x = 12;
int K = 10;
int Q = 10;
int J = 10;
int Ace();

int dealer = rand() % 11 + 1;
std::vector<int> Cards = { Ace(),K,Q,J,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 };
int value;

do {
    std::vector<int> dh = { };
    do
    {
        int i = dh.size();
        dh.insert(dh.begin() + (i), Cards[distr(eng)]);

    } while (dh.size() < 2); {

        if (dh[0] + dh[1] < 21)
        {
            int ph = dh[0] + dh[1];
            string input;
            cout << dh[0] << "," << dh[1] << "\n";
            cout << "Your total is " << ph << "\n" << "Do you want to hit or stay? ";
            cin >> input;

        }
        else
        {

        }


    }


} while (Cards[distr(eng)] < 1000);
{
    puts("STOP!");
    return 0;
}

}
int Ace() {
  int x;
  cout << "You drew an Ace! " << "\n" << "Do you want to make it 11 or 1?";
  cin >> x;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: If you put paranetheses it will call the function. For example `{ Ace(),K,Q,J,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2 };` is calling Ace. You will need to do some refactoring and rethinking how this is going to work. One way to do this is with placeholder for Ace like you do with the other royal cards, and if the card drawn is an Ace then you call the Ace function and get the value you want.

Comment: @KevinWelch so do `int Ace = Ace()` or do `int Ace = 11`

Comment: Your problem is a little more complicated than that. Doing `int Ace = Ace()` will call still call the function once at the very beginning of your program. However, you can set it to `11` and if an Ace is drawn then you can call the Ace function to give the card a value. If that isn't clear to you, then you might want to go back to learning more of the basics.